# Questions about uploading multiple images with any API

Tags: api, file-upload, cloud, backend, storage

I have some questions about uploading images to cloud storage, I wish someone could help me. I would like answers according to best practices:

1. Which is better, send the images to my API with all other form information and then send them to the cloud or upload them to the cloud directly via Frontend and separate from other form information?
2. Do I need to make a request for each image or is it better to upload all images directly?

Answer (score 0):

1. Backend generates a signed url at which the client uploads the video directly - this requires solid authentication
2. Depends if the client has a good internet connection or not but batching is usually good